# Como contar quantos dias da semana (segunda, terça....) tem em um período de 1 mês?

Tags: sql, postgresql, firebird

Preciso de ajuda para retornar em um SQL a quantidade que tem de cada dia da semana em um período de 1 mes, por exemplo no mês 06/2021 tem 4 segundas,5 terças,5 quartas...etc.
Preciso saber a quantidade de todos os dias da semana, pois preciso fazer uma média com esse valor.
Tentei de varias formas mas não deu certo, preciso que seja em SQL Firebird. Obrigada.
Abaixo esta uma das formas que tentei, ele retorna para todos os dias da semana a quantidade de 560:

```
SELECT sum(iif(EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM N.DTEMISSAO) = 1, 1, 0)) qt_segunda,
        sum(iif(EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM N.DTEMISSAO) = 1, 1, 0)) qt_terca,
        sum(iif(EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM N.DTEMISSAO) = 1, 1, 0)) qt_quarta,
        sum(iif(EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM N.DTEMISSAO) = 1, 1, 0)) qt_quinta,
        sum(iif(EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM N.DTEMISSAO) = 1, 1, 0)) qt_sexta,
        sum(iif(EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM N.DTEMISSAO) = 1, 1, 0)) qt_sabado,
        sum(iif(EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM N.DTEMISSAO) = 1, 1, 0)) qt_domingo
FROM NOTA N
WHERE N.DTEMISSAO BETWEEN '01.06.2021' AND '30.06.2021'
```

Comment: faça um `group by` por data (por dia no seu caso)

Comment: Não funcionou, deu o erro: Cannot use an aggregate function in a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @RicardoPontual coloque o seu código como resposta, se não funcionar só excluir

Comment: qual a diferença da coluna dtemissao para data_emissao?

Comment: Nenhuma, escrevi errado, vou arrumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso não é muito simples por causa de algumas coisas:

- É preciso agrupar por datas, mas pode haver mais de um registro na mesma data, por isso é necessário fazer um `DISTINCT`;
- Para fazer um `DISTINCT`, é necessário fazer numa *subquery*, ou seja primeiro retornar todas as datas únicas;
- Esse `SUM` não faz sentido, poderia ser um `COUNT`, de qualquer forma é preciso separar os dias, então uma melhor opição seria usar um `CASE WHEN`.

Dito isso, vamos à query:

```
select case 
         when extract(dow from dados.data)=0 THEN 'DOM'
         when extract(dow from dados.data)=1 THEN 'SEG'
         when extract(dow from dados.data)=2 THEN 'TER'
         when extract(dow from dados.data)=3 THEN 'QUA'
         when extract(dow from dados.data)=4 THEN 'QUI'
         when extract(dow from dados.data)=5 THEN 'SEX'
         when extract(dow from dados.data)=6 THEN 'SAB'
       end dia,
       count(extract(dow from dados.data)) tot
 from (select distinct dtemissao as data
        from nota) dados
group by extract(dow from dados.data)
order by extract(dow from dados.data);
```

Observações:

- A *subquery* `select distinct dtemissao as data`, chamada de "data", vai retornar as datas únicas. Note que se suas datas tiverem hora vai ser preciso remover a data para agrupar correto;
- Para identificar o dia da semana foi usado `extract(dow from dados.data)=0`, para saber mais, veja a documentação: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-datetime.html
- No final, agrupou pelo mesmo critério `extract(dow from dados.data)` que fez o `COUNT`.

Pode ver funcionando aqui: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b293b/20), inseri algumas data para o exemplo

Comment: Obrigada, deu certo. Fiz alguns ajustes para funcionar em SQL Firebird. Query abaixo 
`
SELECT CASE EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM N.DIAS)
            WHEN 1 THEN 'SEGUNDA'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'TERCA'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'QUARTA'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'QUINTA'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'SEXTA'
            WHEN 6 THEN 'SABADO'
            WHEN 0 THEN 'DOMINGO'
            END SEMANA,
       COUNT(EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM N.DIAS)) QTDE
 FROM(  SELECT DISTINCT DTEMISSAO AS DIAS
    FROM NOTA )N
WHERE N.DIAS BETWEEN '01.06.2021' AND '30.06.2021'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM N.DIAS)
`

Comment: bom, não esqueça de votar ou marcar a resposta como aceita se resolveu a sua dúvida :)